# query manytoOne field

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a reflexive field in mysql (yeah the one with a foreign key pointing at the same table).

This one is a product and the foreign key must tell me if the product is part of a package (this is a design decision).

```
     @Column(name = "servicio")
    private Boolean servicio;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productosidProductos")
    private List<Productos> productosList;
    @JoinColumn(name = "productos_idProductos", referencedColumnName = "idProductos")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Productos productosidProductos;


@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idProductos")
    private Integer idProductos;
```

and I get this one

> Problem compiling [SELECT e FROM Productos e JOIN e.productosidProductos p JOIN e.productosidProductos p2 WHERE p2.productosidProductos > 0]. 
>   [93, 116] The relationship mapping 'p2.productosidProductos' cannot be used in conjunction with the > operator

when I run this

```
 Query paquetesQuery = EclipseLinkUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createQuery("SELECT e FROM Productos e JOIN e.productosidProductos p JOIN e.productosidProductos p2 WHERE p2.productosidProductos > 0");
```

this runs very well

```
 Query paquetesQuery = EclipseLinkUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createQuery("SELECT e FROM  "
            + "Productos e WHERE e.productosidProductos IS NOT NULL");
```

but I need this where WHERE e.productosidProductos > 0 because when the product is not a part of a group will be 0.
 thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write this in Java, can you?

```
Productos product =  new Productos(...);
if (product > 0)
```

No you can't, because a product is a product. It's not a number. So comparing a product with 0 makes no sense. But you're doing it in your query:

```
WHERE p2.productosidProductos > 0
```

where the `productosidProductos` attribute is of type `Productos`. If you want to compare the ID of the product, which is an Integer, with 0, then that would work:

```
WHERE p2.productosidProductos.id > 0
```

Comment: oh my god! thank you very much i was blind if i couldn't see this one ! i belived that p2.productosidProductos was just a property not an entity but the error was telling that type was not correct!